# App module disappeared in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I had app module running on my android studio project until I pressed delete by mistake. I am now unable to run my project as it doesn't detect app module.

I can see app folder in project view (containing build, libs, src folders) but I don't see it in android view or configuration setting where it says

I have an old apk file of the project.

I shared my project on github.
Please help me get my module back so that I can run my project.

Comment: If you're using github, try checkout to your project! `git checkout .` but it will remove all changes from last commit.

Answer (score 14):

All I had to do was File->Sync project with gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

In order to not risk and further modify your content, try and clone again your android repo elsewhere and see if your module shows up there.

If it does, copy it back in your current repo.

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, twice now. The first time, a full clean/rebuild did the trick. The second time, this didn't work. What did resolve the problem was opening the `settings.gradle` file and copying everything, then removing it to leave an empty file. Then save and resync Gradle. This failed, but then I pasted the old contents back into the file and did a resync again, which then fixed the issue.

Not sure what the problem was in the first place, but this worked for me so I figured I'd share.